# Unity Editor Windows App some icons Not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am new to UNITY and installed Unity 2021.3.0f1. Application is loading fine, but certain icons are greyed and icon is not showing. Currently i am using i3 processor with 6GB RAM. Can anyone please say why the icons are displaying, but the functionality are working fine.
**Please find the below System Inofrmation** 
Device name DESKTOP-CA3F243  
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz   3.30 GHz  
Installed RAM   6.00 GB (5.90 GB usable)  
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor  
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display  

Please find the below screenshot by runing the Code snippet, no icons are showing.

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Cdi.png" />
```

Comment: Are you sure your machine meets all requirements. Especially as you dont mention the all important graphic card. If you only have 6gb which sounds tight

Comment: I have the same problem in Unity 2021.3.13f.  Have you solved this issue?